# I need help with a commutator!

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, differentiation, commutator

In QM class this morning my Prof claimed that the commutator $$[(/), (/)] = 0.$$

However, my classmate and I arrived at $$x(/x) - y(/y).$$

Our professor used the identity $$[f(x,y)/x] = {[g(x)/x] * [h(y)/x]}$$ and the fact that $[h(y)/x] = 0$ to arrive at her solution, but I am not familiar or comfortable with this identity. Is it for a special case?

Can anyone explain how (or if) our professor is correct?
Her solution is as follows:
[image: Professor's Solution]

Comment: Your expressions are not even nonsense, for generic *f(x,y)* ; they are meaningless. Clarify what further properties you think it has.

Comment: @CosmasZachos That is pretty much what my classmate said to the professor! The reply was, "I'm a physics Prof not a math Prof, and this is what I was shown to do" Very Unsatisfying.

Comment: The third line is a tautology. The transition from the 5th to the 6th line is meaningless.  As I indicated below, in a comment, you get zero for any function $f(x,y)=g(xy)$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I see now that this is valid for f(x,y) = g(x^m * y^n) when n=m. I am still puzzled why my professor would use such a specific case in what is otherwise supposed to be a general solution. 
Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Let's see,
$$[x\partial_y,y\partial_x]\phi(x,y)=x\partial_y(y\partial_x \phi(x,y))-y\partial_x(x\partial_y\phi(x,y))\\
=x(\partial_x \phi+y\partial_y\partial_x\phi)-y(\partial_y\phi+x\partial_x\partial_y\phi)\\
=x\partial_x\phi-y\partial_y\phi=(x\partial_x-y\partial_y)\phi$$
It's look like you are right!

The fact that your professor used to prove the commutation relation zero i.e. $\phi=\psi(x)\chi(y)$ is not true in general. If it's true then
$$x\partial_x(\psi \chi)-y\partial_y(\psi\chi)=x\chi\partial_x\psi-y\psi\partial_y\chi\not=0$$
Even then it's not zero.

The identity that you have given is wrong. Since
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} g(x) h(y)=h(y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(x)$$
It's not zero.

Comment: By solving the evident differential equation, you find the  commutator only   vanishes acting on the highly restricted class of functions *()* . But the OP never specified that.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi Thank you for this! I am glad I am not the only one to reach this result.
I appreciate the help.